# Return to original page after PHP script send video

Tags: php, html, html5-video

---

Is there a way to jump back to original page after video has finished playing?
I call PHP from link to video in HTML

```
...
<a href="play.php">My Video
...
```

and play.php  sends back video
like this:

```
<?php
$CTYP= 'video/mp4';
$VidPath = "../MyVideo.mp4";  
header('Content-Type: ' . $CTYP);
$VidFl = fopen($VidPath, "rb");
$VidContent = fread($VidFl, filesize($VidPath));
fclose($VidFl);
echo $VidContent; 
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Not the way you've done it because you're literally just displaying the video file directly. The browser takes over at that point. Maybe in some browsers it won't even be displayed, just downloaded. You'd have to instead display a HTML page which has the video embedded in it, and use some JavaScript to detect the end of the video and then make the browser navigate back

Comment: As already suggested, create a HTML page and use the `video` tag. There you can subscribe to the [ended](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp) event which is triggered after playing a video.

Comment: Thanks Markus and ADyson, looks like the better option is then with video tag.  Although in that case video is already taking space on the page, and in case of many videos, web pages fills up.  I'd rather just have links, and on click it would open ideally in lightbox

Comment: You can still have a link to a page which then just has one video on it! Or yes you could use lightbox instead - and then maybe just close the lightbox when the video has finished.

Comment: Hi ADyson,  would you be so kind to show me example to open in lightbox and then close it?

Comment: pretty sure lightbox's website would have a tutorial on how to open and close it. And Markus already gave you a link to how you detect the video has finished. Put those two things together and you should be fine. Is there something specific confusing you, which isn't clear from that? have you tried anything? We're not here to provide you with tutorials or documentation (that's what search engines are for). If you've found something, tried to make it work, and still failed, that's where we come in.

Comment: Sorry ADyson, I was pursuing different other possibility ie to substitute path within <video> tag on original page, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update, to a partial solution based on the feedback I received, I updated php script to send back <video> tag and open new page, with event (vid.onend) to go to previous page after video ends.
So to anyone with similar problem here is updated code
**index.html**  has

```
...
<a href="play.php">My Video
...
```

and my **play.php** file is like this

```
<?php
$VidPath = "../MyVideo.mp4";  
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="video.css" media="screen,print" />'
<title>Test Video play list</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<video id="MyVideo" height="auto" width="auto" controls autoplay > <source src=<?php echo $VidPath; ?> type="video/mp4"> </video>
<script>
  var vid = document.getElementById("MyVideo"); 
  vid.onended = function() { 
    history.back(); 
  }; 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a good option to:

- play video in empty page and style it with CSS so can look practically like lightbox without any JS or outside code
- after video ends, I can automatically jump back to original list

But still can't:

- specify path outside of root folder of the website
- firefox seems not want to do autoplay, so extra click is necessary
- play video in same page as my index.html that would look like lightbox efect

Hope for some more tips
D

Comment: If you want to specify a file outside the site root, make your `src=` of the video tag point to a PHP script which has similar functionality to the original "play.php" in your question, except that it takes an ID or filename as input (e.g. `src="getvideo.php?file=123.mp4"`) and uses that to decide which exact file content to return. If you make it accept filenames rather than IDs, make sure it's sanitised and secure, and can't be used to pull down files from outside the location you want to allow. Personally I'd store records of the video paths in a database and let the script look it up there

Comment: Autoplay is at the user's discretion. You can't force that (thankfully, considering all those horrible video ads we'd get otherwise). Different browsers implement it in subtly different ways, but they all have published info about how it works.

Comment: `play video in same page as my index.html that would look like lightbox efect`...that's the subject of a whole new question.

Comment: I have tried to have \<video> tag in the index html like:
`<video height="auto" width="200" controls autoplay>
    <source src="play.php?play_video=106" type="video/mp4">
 </video>`
and **play.php** supplied back path, but it doesn't work.  Shows "No Video supported format"

Comment: And I plan to put all file paths in mysql table, but I need to have it working directly first.  I implemented database in any case in order to check username, and see if they should be able to watch video at all

Comment: Does `play.php?play_video=106` work ok if you access it directly in the browser - does it provide the video file correctly?

Comment: @ADyson yes now is working, I had some mistakes in the code, that it looked like is only playing if from within the website root folder not outside... Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

Final update for anyone who has a similar problem, It is now working version with original approach modified based on suggestions (should've probably read more carefully to avoid running around the solution:).

so **index.html** with <video> tags

```
....
<tr><td>
  <video height="auto" width="200" controls >
    <source src="play.php?play_video=101" type="video/mp4"> 
 </video>        
</td> <td>Lecture 101....</td>
</tr><tr><td>
  <video height="auto" width="200" controls >
    <source src="play.php?play_video=102" type="video/mp4">
  </video>        
</td> <td>Lecture 102....</td> 
</tr>
....
```

and **play.php** return stream like originally to href link tag

```
<?php
include 'dblog.php';
if ( ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === "GET")
     && ( isset($_GET['play_video']) ) ) {
  if ($_GET['play_video'] == "101")  {
    $file_path_name = "../../DVD/Lecture-101.mp4";
  } elseif ($_GET['play_video'] == "102") {
    $file_path_name = "../../DVD/Lecture-102.mp4";
  }
  $ctype= 'video/mp4';
  header('Content-Type: ' . $ctype);
  $handle = fopen($file_path_name, "rb");
  $contents = fread($handle, filesize($file_path_name));
  fclose($handle);
  write_vid_log($_GET['play_video'], $DB, 'start');
  echo $contents; 
} else {
  echo "alert(I'm Sorry wrong link)";
}
?>
```

So now works to be able to supply links outside of www root folder, and it plays video when client clicks. A few more challenges:

- links to media files are easy downloadable, even though path, and file name is not shown, so I need use PHP script to check user and his rights before streaming video file
- use CSS to resize and center video over the page, once clicked to play, and can be made seen as if it's playing in the lightbox. Looks like this is possible even without any JS

Any extra suggestions, would be appreciated

Comment: This is great. Glad you got it working. I like how you are breaking the challenge down into the different steps, and getting small parts working before tackling the next bit. This is a good approach which is effective for programmers. I see too many people seeing their entire application as one massive block where the different parts can't be tested separately. So you are doing things in a good way...good luck with the rest of the project. Come back here of course with new questions if you need to, about the next steps.